# Getting error while rising a post request on react mongo db

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, postman

please help me to solve the below problem. When iam trying to add user to the db its showing the error `"Error:MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.users index: username_1 dup key: { : null }"`

below is the post request which i requested.

```
{
    "name":"dddd",
    "email":"thomaslss",
    "password":"ssss",
    "mobilenumber":"ssss"
}
```

below is the user scheme for mongo db

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema ({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required:true,
        unique:true,
        trim:true,
        minlength:3
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required:true,
        unique:true,
        minlength:3
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required:true,
        minlength:3
    },
    mobilenumber:{
        type:Number,
        required:true,
        minlength:3
    },

},{
    timestamps:true,
}

);

const User =mongoose.model ('User',userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

below is the onSumbit method when iam submitting the data

```
  onSubmitHandler=(e)=>{
                    e.preventDefault();

                    const user={
                        name:this.state.name,
                        email:this.state.email,
                        password:this.state.password,
                        mobilenumber:this.state.mobilenumber
                    }
                    console.log(user);
                    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/users/add',user)
                    .then(res=>console.log(res.data));
    }

find the back end code which i wrote

const router =require ('express').Router();
let User = require('../models/user.model');


router.route('/').get((req,res)=>{
    User.find()
    .then(users=>res.json(users))
    .catch(err=> res.status(400).json('Error:'+err))
});


router.route('/add').post((req,res)=>{
    const name= req.body.name;
    const email= req.body.email;
    const password= req.body.password;    
    const mobilenumber= req.body.mobilenumber;    


    const newUser = new User({name,email,password,mobilenumber});

    newUser.save()
    .then(()=>res.json("user added"))
    .catch(err=> res.status(400).json('Error:'+err))
});

module.exports = router;
```

Note: i have checked in mongo db data base but there were no any duplicated values for the fields

below is the mongo db datas present in the db

```
[{"_id":"5d9aaff88709f423740e8a37","name":"seee","email":"rrrt","password":"fftyg","mobilenumber":45778,"createdAt":"2019-10-07T03:24:40.642Z","updatedAt":"2019-10-07T03:24:40.642Z","__v":0}]
```

please help me to solve the issue. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be an error on your backend. Your react code looks fine, and if you are displaying the user object correctly when you console log it, your parameters should be sent correctly. Are you 100% sure that your state variables are not undefined before sending the request? Would you mind sharing your backend code that handles this?